# How to measure distance/position accurately?

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor, distance

I am wondering if there is a way to measure distance between two movable points (e.g., the first point is on the hand and the second point is on the back of the human body).

I was looking at different types of technologies. I found ultrasonic sensors but those need a reflective object and this does not work with my idea. I thought about separating the transmitter and the receiver but there is the human body (hip) between those points and it can not be face to face. I considered technology based on magnetic fields so it can be measured regardless of obstacles or motion but I did not find anything close to what I want. And for infrared it needs to detect some object.

Is there any technology that can help me achieve this type of requirement?

Comment: Tape measures still work but although you haven't mentioned it I suspect you want it automated and regular without a 3rd party being involved. It's all about clearly defining what you want!!

Comment: What came to my mind were 1. [calipers](http://blog.spacetec.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/caliper-exterior1.png). 2. [motion capture suit](http://www.sfdm.scad.edu/intranet/students/cage/eqimages/mocapsuit.jpg). :-)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Motion capture suits are neat. Wonder why they aren't part of the video-gaming scene yet. A bit bulky but surely it can be made more elegant with some R&D.

Comment: Linearly "sloped" magnetic field with coil pickups. Up to 3 coils at 90 degrees if rotation involved. This method is used in body motion telemetering systems for movies et al.  Less secrecy of application will help answer quality.

Comment: @boardbite - The thing is, motion capture suits aren't just a suit, it's a suit, a BUNCH of cameras shooting from every angle, a backdrop that makes using CV techniques to extract the position of the nodes on the suit easier, and a whole bunch of software to glue it all together. It's not really something you could package up easily.

Comment: What are the use case/constraints? Ie, outdoors,indoors? mobile or stationary?

A series of linked rods with multi-axis rotary encoders at each joint would do the trick for indoors/outdoors, provided you have a small MCU or computer to gather and calculate the values for you. 

Give the known lengths and dimensions, you would be able to calculate point to point distance as well as path of arm distance. 

No RF/IR involved, unless you want to have the signal relayed via RF to a computer.

Another option would be a smartphone with accelerometer/gravity sensor to measure the movement/deltas.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't suggested that the sensor should not physically interact with the body being measured, so given that I'm going to suggest a spool of line (automatically retracting) and a rotary encoder.  You might need two spools to allow trigonometry to calculate the actual distance to the hand.